# How to indicate that a JMSTemplate.receive() should use a DurableSubscriber

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms, ems

I want to do this without using the xml configuration. I am toying with Spring JMS to see if it meets my needs. Is there anyway of doing a synchronous receive using the

```
JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
jmsTemplate.receive()
```

so that it is equivalent to the pure JMS call:

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createDurableSubscriber(topic, "durable name");
Message message = consumer.receive();
```

Without needing to configure through xml?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , but how are you planning to call this ?

> ```
>   //Create connection facotry ..in this case JndiObjectFactoryBean because i am looking up a JNDI
>   org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean connectionFactory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
>   connectionFactory.setJndiName(jndiName);
>   connectionFactory.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate);
>
>   org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate template = new org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate();
>   template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
>   template.setPubSubDomain(false);
>
>   Message message = template.receive();
> ```

For more info check 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#receive%28%29

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-receiving-sync